# PhoneGap app crashes with "unrecognized selector" error

Tags: cordova

I have a basic PhoneGap project, 100% auto-generated code. The app starts, and immediately crashes on the second line:

```
int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); // exception
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

The exception is `[__NSCFString count] unrecognized selector sent to instance`. It seems something expected a string, and got a `nil` instead. Is there some configuration setting I am supposed to set?

Edit: I am using XCode 4.2.1.

Thanks.

Comment: which phonegap version are you using??

Comment: I was using 1.3, and this morning I upgraded to 1.5. That didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It was my fault.

My app needs to communicate with a Web service, so I changed the `ExternalHosts` setting in the .plist file to `*`. The problem was that instead of adding an item to the array, I had changed the type to String. After changing it back to Array, everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code:

```
int main(int args, char* argv[]) {
    //NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); // exception
    //[pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: Tried that - same thing. It's not related to reference counting.

Comment: yes i realized that it would be something else. did you try to run any phonegap-ios template projects??

Answer (score 0):

For me, I rearranged my plugin parameters in javascript but did not reflect those changes in my backend code... which seems like a "no duh" type of thing but a result of a simple oversight.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796542/error-phonegap-xcode/20411543#20411543) for more details.