# error phonegap xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have a phonegap project on android.
This woeks well but when I compile on the phonegap website I have some problems on the ios version.

So I try using xcode using the xcode simulator but I have the folloing error:

```
2013-04-03 21:29:27.261 Assas[2339:c07] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-04-03 21:29:28.455 Assas[2339:c07] [LOG] true
2013-04-03 21:29:28.940 Assas[2339:c07] -[__NSCFArray    dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8939150
2013-04-03 21:29:28.942 Assas[2339:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:]:     unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8939150'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14c012 0x25a2e7e 0x1d74bd 0x13bbbc 0x13b94e 0x163b0 0x16243 0x5bbdb 0x5b32c 0x5aedd     0x5b075 0x5af93 0x25b66b0 0x1125765 0xcff3f 0xcf96f 0xf2734 0xf1f44 0xf1e1b 0x33d37e3     0x33d3668 0x387ffc 0x214c 0x20a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I take the content of my www folder in my android project, I just change the config.xml and the cordova jsfile

I'm using phonegap 2.4.0 on both projects

edit:

the error is in Others Sources/main.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

on line 6

Thanks

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this issue? I am struggling with this currently...

Comment: hi, in my case it was due to a wrong json feed

Comment: Hi ant, can you explain a bit more? In my case it throws the exception when I try to save JSON to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The cordova javascript is different for Android and ios. So when you copy your www, make sure you replace android's cordova.js by ios's cordova.js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I change my dordova.js

Answer (score 0):

Your application is using Automatic Reference Counting (which is new) and Phonegap doesn't support it yet. The solution is below:

1.
Go to your project's build settings and turn Automatic Reference Counting to off.
Build Settings-User Defined-CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC- change from YES to NO

2.
Dangerous/bad but solve the error: delete the @autoreleasepool, code seems to be 
`int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
        return retVal;
}`

Comment: Thanks, I set CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC to no and I also try removing @autoreleasepool but in each cases I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For me, I rearranged the order of a plugin's parameters in my plugin's javascript file but I did not reflect those changes in the iOS code.  I am sending a mix of strings, longs, and ints in my plugin parameters:

```
// Old javascript
cordova.exec(success, fail, "MyPlugin", "PluginMethod", [0, 758493037474, "String"]);

// New javascript
cordova.exec(success, fail, "MyPlugin", "PluginMethod", ["String", 0, 758493037474]);
```

Make sure to update your backend code too (no duh, right!!!)

```
// Old objective C
int myid              = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
double mydouble       = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
NSString *mystring    = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:2];

// New objective C
NSString *mystring    = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
int myid              = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];
double mydouble       = [[command.arguments objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
```